# SPARQL Query for searching all properties of one type to match a string

Tags: string, search, filter, match, sparql

I am trying to construct a SPARQL Query to search through all of the properties of a type. For example, I would like to search through the Person type (http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#Person) and return Person instances where their properties are matched to the input string "ken". This is the current query I'm using:

```
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX ui:    <http://uispin.org/ui#>
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT * 
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys> {
        ?subject a <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#Person>;
                    ?property ?value . 

        FILTER EXISTS {
                        ?subject ?anyProperty ?anyValue .
                        FILTER (isLiteral(?anyValue) && regex(xsd:string(?anyValue), "1956", "i")) .
            } .
    }
}
```

And the above query returns me this:

[image: Result 1]

This is correct in matching the property birthYear and returned 3 instances. But when I search for "male", and want to return all Person instances that matched to male, I don't get what I expected.

Query

```
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX ui:    <http://uispin.org/ui#>
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT * 
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys> {
        ?subject a <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#Person>;
                    ?property ?value . 

        FILTER EXISTS {
                        ?subject ?anyProperty ?anyValue .
                        FILTER (isLiteral(?anyValue) && regex(xsd:string(?anyValue), "male", "i")) .
            } .
    }
}
```

[image: Result 2]

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. What's surprising in the second result?  You're doing a case insensitive regex match and there's the triple

```
:SydneyLawford :middleName "Maleia"
```

`"Maleia"` certainly matches `"male"` (since the match is case insensitive).  If you want the value to have the string `"male"` exactly, try a slightly different `filter`:

```
FILTER (isLiteral(?anyValue) && lcase(str(?anyValue)) = "male")
```

Comment: In kennedys ontology, gender is an object property. Its values are resources not literals. So the query must search on the object labels. I posted the answer here as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, but your original query had been using `isLiteral`, too.  It's easy enough to remove it, and use _just_ `lcase(str(?anyValue)) = "male"`.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the final query. I broke it down in two parts. The first will search through all of the property values of the Person type. The second part gets the rdfs:label of the objects in the values. So an example of that would be the property value http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#female would have a label as female. The query will match to that instead. The two results will be unioned at the end.

```
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX ui:    <http://uispin.org/ui#>


SELECT distinct ?subject  
  WHERE {
    {
      GRAPH <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys> {

        ?subject a <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#Person> . 

        ?subject ?property ?value .

        FILTER (isLiteral(?value) && regex(str(?value), "1956", "i")) .
      }
    }
    UNION
    {
      GRAPH <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys> {

        ?subject a <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#Person> . 

        ?subject ?property ?value .

        ?property rdfs:label ?propertyName . 
        ?value rdfs:label ?valueName . 

        FILTER regex(?valueName, "female") . 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since nothing in `1956` is actually a regular expression, you could check with `contains(str(?value),"1956")` and not invoke the regular expression matcher.

Comment: You can also simplify this query significantly, e.g., http://pastebin.com/xSkpcBNR .